# I can't access the json file in c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, macos

I already put the access as being 'read/write' so everyone including me can read and write to the json file. However, the code is still sending out an **UnauthorizedAccessException** afterwards. This is the code:

```
public static void read_json(string path)
        {

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("/Users/steve/Downloads/city_list.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                List<City_Data> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<City_Data>>(json);

                foreach (City_Data item in items)
                {
                    var key = item.name;
                    var value = item.id;
                    dict.Add(key, value);
                }
            }

        }
```

while this is part of the json file which I have been wanting to access and read from:

```
[
  {
    "id": 833,
    "name": "Ḩeşār-e Sefīd",
    "state": "",
    "country": "IR",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 47.159401,
      "lat": 34.330502
    }
  },
...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make all files writeable when checking out of source control.

Call the Attrib MSBuild task before the transformation to remove the read-only file attribute.
For example:

```
<Attrib Files="/Users/steve/Downloads/city_list.json" Normal="true"/>
```

Call the Exec MSBuild task before the transformation to remove the read-only file attribute.
For example:

```
<Exec Command="attrib -R &quot;/Users/steve/Downloads/city_list.json&quot;"/>
```

Comment: How do you get to the conclussion of source control being the problem?

Comment: Do we put this into this into the xaml file?